Can Martial Characters use Spell Scrolls in D&D 2024?
I am finding a lot of conflicting rules between the new material that came out recently. The Scriptorium special facility under the Bastion Rules in the 2024 DMG say...

Prerequisite: None


Craft: Spell Scroll. You commission the facility’s hireling to scribe a Spell Scroll... the hireling meets all the prerequisites needed to scribe the scroll.

According to this, anyone can get a Scriptorium and make their own spell scrolls. The rules for a Spell Scroll, however, say...

If the spell is on your spell list, you can read the scroll and cast its spell... Otherwise, the scroll is unintelligible.

Let's say a player's Monk or Barbarian gets a Scriptorium for their Bastion and has the hireling write out a Fireball Spell Scroll for them. RAW, they would not be able to cast the spell. They would have to give the scroll to a Wizard or Sorcerer in the party for it to even be used. So why is this option available for martial characters if they can't even use their own stuff? Are spell scrolls crafted this way available for the bastion's owner, the player, able to be cast by that player?

The other answer covers the title question, but as an answer to the sub question of:

So why is this option available for martial characters if they can't even use their own stuff?

Scrolls have use outside of casting. Most scrolls above first level will fetch a good price in an open market. Generally speaking, most player-craftable items require half of the market price to craft. For scrolls in particular, the 2024 DMG says the following under the "Magic Items Rarities and Values" table:

The value of a Spell Scroll is double what it costs to scribe the scroll

Taking the spell scroll creation costs from the 2024 PHB, the mentioned Fireball scroll would take five days to craft and cost 150GP in materials. Based on the DMG rule, this same scroll would sell for 300GP netting a nice 150GP in profit. Making 150GP per work-week seems like a fantastic reason for martials to have their hirelings craft scrolls.
Additionally, giving the scroll to other party members shouldn't be overlooked. Even if they could also have their own hirelings crafting for them, two scrolls of fireball on a wizard is always better than one!

Any reason why you would use the Xanathar scroll crafting costs for a 2024 5e question when the 2024 PHB provides updated scroll crafting costs and times?

It might be that they don't have access to the 2024 PHB, or not have seen the tag for the system. In any case, Andrew, the new cost for crafting a 3rd level spell scroll is 150gp and takes 5 days - feel free to use that in your answer.

It looks like the 2024 DMG says "The value of a Spell Scroll is double what it costs to scribe the scroll," right under the Magic Items Rarities and Values table. So if you sold a Spell Scroll you would get 300gp off of it.

Thanks for the info from the newer sources! Dani is right, I don't have access to any of the newer books yet. I've updated my answer to include both of the notes.

There’s no need to signal edits in the body of the post. The site already says it was revised and allows you to write in a comment when making the edit describing the revision.

+1 for the last paragraph. Scroll of Revify pinned toyour chest with diamond brooch can be very helpful sometimes ;)

No
The rules for spell scrolls still require that the spell be on your spell list to cast it. The bastion rules don't change that. As for why martials are able to create them, only the designers know. But martial characters can't really create them anyway; they can hire someone to do it. And martials can hire people just as well as a wizard.
